# How to add/sum the input values in an HTML Form?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to total the hours/values for each column/day but get a blank result and I don't get any errors in console to provide any information on what I am doing wrong.

**HTML Form**

```
<form>
<table>
 <tr>
     <th> MONDAY </th>
     <th> TUESDAY </th>
     <th> WEDNESDAY </th>
     <th> THURSDAY </th>
     <th> FRIDAY </th>
     <th> SATURDAY </th>
     <th> SUNDAY </th>
 </tr>
<?php

$q = "SELECT * FROM workHours";
$r = mysqli_query($conn, $q);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
$db_mon = $row['mon'];
$db_tues = $row['tues'];
$db_wed = $row['wed'];
$db_thurs = $row['thurs'];
$db_fri = $row['fri'];
$db_sat = $row['sat'];
$db_sun = $row['sun'];

echo "

<tr>
    <td> <input name='mon' type='number' value='$db_mon' onblur='findMonTotal()'></td>
    <td> <input name='tues' type='number' value='$db_tues' onblur='findTuesTotal()'></td>
    <td> <input name='wed' type='number' value='$db_wed' onblur='findWedTotal()'></td>
    <td> <input name='thurs' type='number' value='$db_thurs' onblur='findThursTotal()'></td>
    <td> <input name='fri' type='number' value='$db_fri' onblur='findFriTotal()'></td>
    <td> <input name='sat' type='number' value='$db_sat' onblur='findSatTotal()'></td>
    <td> <input name='sun' type='number' value='$db_sun' onblur='findSunTotal()'></td>
</tr>

";
}

?>

<tr>
   <td> <input type="number" id="monTotal" readonly> </td>
   <td> <input type="number" id="tuesTotal" readonly> </td>
   <td> <input type="number" id="wedTotal" readonly> </td>
   <td> <input type="number" id="thursTotal" readonly> </td>
   <td> <input type="number" id="friTotal" readonly> </td>
   <td> <input type="number" id="satTotal" readonly> </td>
   <td> <input type="number" id="sunTotal" readonly> </td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
```

**Javascript**
I am using this function for each day.  I tried using "getElementById" but got the same result.

```
function findMonTotal() {
let arr = document.getElementsByName('mon').value;
let Mon = 0;
   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   if(parseFloat(arr[i].value))
      Mon += parseFloat(arr[1].value);
   }

}
document.getElementById('monTotal').value = Mon;
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the mistake that you are just counting for the only first index

```
Mon += parseFloat(arr[1].value);
```

Just replace 1 with i like this like

```
Mon += parseFloat(arr[i].value);
```